# Why Does CKEditor Paste Image Work Here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html

Tags: image, google-chrome, ckeditor, paste

What is so special about CKEditor on this page:

http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-04-04-06-09/full/samples/

that you can effortlessly paste an image into the editor with a Chrome Browser?  By effortlessly I mean:

1. Cut image to clipboard
2. Move cursor into editor.
3. Place cursor where you want image.
4. Ctrl-V

and you are done...just like in FF.  This is the only sample CKEditor I have seen that allows such a convenient pasting.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by 'special', but if you're curious how it works...

How IT does it specifically would take too long to decipher as it's annoyingly obfuscated. Set a breakpoint at the first return of the word "paste" when you ctrl+f it (in ckeditor.js through dev console) and proceed to step through if you're brave. I got most of the way before I accepted it wasn't anything unique and not worth my time.

What's special about it? Nothing really... Trigger the event onPaste, get the images from the clipboard if they exist and read it .getAsFile, and then read said blob (output from .getAsFile) using .readAsDataURL and insert the result into an img elements src attribute.

Example:

```
<textarea id="pasteArea" placeholder="Paste Image Here"></textarea>
<img id="pastedImage"></img>


document.getElementById('pasteArea').onpaste = function(event) {
  // use event.originalEvent.clipboard for newer chrome versions
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  var blob = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
      blob = items[i].getAsFile();
    }
  }

  if (blob !== null) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      document.getElementById("pastedImage").src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry.  What I mean by special is:

Comment: I don't think what you intended to put happened. What did you mean?

Comment: What I mean by special is, Ctrl-V in a Chrome Browser does not consistently paste an image into CKEditor.    Here are two pages where CTRL-V does not work:     http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html    and    http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/full/ckeditor/samples/  .   On the other hand, CTRL-V does work on these pages:    ckeditor.com   and http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html

Comment: It worked exactly the same for me on all 3 links you provided while using Chrome. The last one only differed a little, in that a banner appeared confirming the image was added successfully.

Comment: All of the links you gave use different versions of CKEditor... first link = version 4.6.2, second link = 4.7.1, and the third link is 4.5.0 beta (Standard)... The link in your original question uses version 4.7.1 (Full)... Despite this, while using Chrome, I noticed no difference in the copy paste functionality of images.... but there's is obviously the chance that what you're experiencing changes based on what version you're using.